# Bonita bmp 7 : bind JSON data to table

Tags: json, business-process-management, bonita

I'm a new in Bonita bpm. I receive data from my connector in the form as a json string. 
There is like connector output param. I store this param like pool variable. 
Then, i get this value with external api:

```
../API/bpm/activityVariable/{{taskId}}/response_rows[enter image description here][1]
```

I got json array like :

```
[{"reason":"reason","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-23T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"1","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-15T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T05:56:02+0000"},{"reason":"reason","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-23T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"2","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-16T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T06:01:26+0000"},{"reason":"test","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-16T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"3","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-16T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T07:26:57+0000"},{"reason":"reason","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-23T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"33","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-22T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T13:25:35+0000"},{"reason":"1111","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-17T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"34","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-17T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T13:26:58+0000"},{"reason":"rrr","createdBy":"4","endDate":"2018-11-30T00:00:00+0000","persistenceId":"35","isApproved":"false","persistenceVersion":"0","startDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00+0000","createtionDate":"2018-11-21T13:29:37+0000"}]
```

I can create json  variable from this json  and set it as a data source.
I see that everything works fine. But when I set the data as External API  variable nothing is displayed in the table.

I use the expression of my variable and not a constant (a small button in the content setting).

How can I show json array as a table ? Is it posiible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately save the API URL as a String Variable

```
    return '../API/bpm/activityVariable/' + $data.taskId + '/response_rows[enter image description here][1]';
```

and use it as URL expression or variable.